# Angular 6 show spinner if Http Response delay more than 2 seconds

Tags: angular

I have this code to intercept http request:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
this.spinner.show();

return next.handle(req).do((event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
  if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
    this.spinner.hide();
  }
}, (err: any) => {
  if (err instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
    // hide spinner
    this.spinner.hide();

    // show error dialog
    let errorMessage = 'An unknown error occurred!';
    if (err.error.message) {
      errorMessage = err.error.message;
    }
    this.dialog.open(ErrorComponent, { data: { message: errorMessage } });
    return throwError(err);
  }
});  }
```

How to make the spinner show only if the http response took more than 2 seconds?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use RxJS timer() operator.

I suggest to do it in a service, where you can operate on your `Observable` object, instead of http interceptor

More info goes in [documentation](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/timer.html).

```
// RxJS v6+
import { timer } from 'rxjs';

//emit 0 after 1 second then complete, since no second argument is supplied
const source = timer(1000);
//output: 0
const subscribe = source.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```